# How to update flutter app programmatically in Play/App store?

Tags: flutter, in-app-update

There is an upgrader (mostly for iOS) and in_app_update plugin (for android). I try to implement them both and had a difficulty to do so. I post and issues in both plugin but I got no response. So if anyone use this 2 plugin successfully please can you share step-by-step approach details.

Basically How to update flutter app programmatically in Google Play Store (Android) & App Store (iOS)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried in_app_update 1.1.11 and upgrader 2.4.0.

For upgrader:

I also don't know how to use Appcast, so I use the iTune api to get my app version in the App Store then pop up the install dialog. However, the iTune api is so slow to update. Therefore I just use Firebase remote config to set the version once the app is published.

For in_app_update:

I also don't know how to use it. I have add the Play Core in app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0'
```

Nothing pop up even I downloaded the old version from the Play Store and then publish a new version.

Update:
I found that in_app_update actually **work** just by following its example code. I don't have any update pop up before because my Android device is **Mi 9**, seems there is some bug in it. The update pop up can be seen in the release version of other brand of devices

Since I really want to use the Play Store in-app-update, so for android I did use the remote config... waiting for someone to have the guides